# Inconsistent C code output with matrix multiplication algorithm

Tags: c, pointers, matrix

I have written the following code to perform a simple matrices multiplication.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void op2(float *a_vec, int m, int n, int p, float *b_vec, float *c_vec){
    float (*a)[n] = (float(*)[n]) a_vec;
    float (*b)[p] = (float(*)[p]) b_vec;
    float (*c)[p] = (float(*)[p]) c_vec;
    int i, j, k;

    for (i = 0; i<m; i++){
        for(j=0; j<p; j++){
            for(k=0; k<n; k++){
                c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
            }
            printf("%.1f ", c[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
}

int main(void){
    float *aVec;
    float *bVec;
    float *cVec;
    int m = 2;
    int n = 3;
    int p = 2;

    float a[6] = {
                1,3,1,
                2,2,2
                };

    aVec = &a[0];

    float b[6] = {
        1,3,
        1,2,
        2,2
        };

    bVec = &b[0];
    float c[4];
    cVec = &c[0];

    op2(aVec, m, n, p, bVec, cVec);
}
```

The resulting vector (printed to output) should be
6.0 11.0
8.0 14.0

Which it is... Most of the time.

However, sometimes it isn't. Sometimes the first value of the array will be incorrect. Most commonly it will be 5.7 or 5.8
5.8 11.0
8.0 14.0

My question is, what am I doing here that is causing this inconsistency? I'm quite new to C and my best guess is that perhaps I'm missing something with relation to the array indices, perhaps I'm running past the end of the array? But I don't see how it would happen inconsistently given that it has the same input, so maybe I'm missing something with pointers?

Have tried:
Declaring array variables outside loops, changing values in input arrays.

Comment: The `c` matrix is uninitialized.

Comment: You use the wrong dimensions for the arrays inside your function.

Comment: And what is the reason for the `aVec` etc. variables? They are simply not needed. And inside the `op2` function, you cast them to the totally wrong type as well. If you want "2D" arrays (arrays of arrays) then *use* arrays of arrays. Don't mess around with different pointer types.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Where do you see wrong dimensions used for the arrays? `a` is 2×3. `b` is 3×2. `c` is 2×2. `m` is 2, `n` is 3, and `p` is 2. In the loops in the function, `a` is accessed by `[i][k]`, and `i` and `k` are bound by `m` and `n` respectively, which are 2 and 3, matching that `a` is 2×3. For `b[k][j]`, `k` and `j` are bound by `n` and `p`, which are 3 and 2, matching that `b` is 3×2. For `c[i][j]`, `i` and `j` are bound by `m` and `p`, which are 2 and 2, matching that `c` is 2×2.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Re “And inside the `op2` function, you cast them to the totally wrong type as well.”: `float (*)[n]`, `float (*)[p]`, and `(float *)[p]` with `n`=3 and `p`=2 are correct types for pointers to the first subarrays `a` (dimensions 2×3), `b` (3×2), and `c` (2×2), respectively. Why do you think they are wrong?

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I also thought the asymmetry in `float (*a)[n]; float (*b)[p]; float (*c)[p];` looked wrong, but indeed, now I agree that it's correct.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Well to begin with `a_vec` is pointing to the first element of an array of `m` elements, not `n`. That `m == n` in this example doesn't really make it right I think. Secondly, `a_vec` (and the other pointers) are pointers to to the *first elements* of arrays, not to the arrays themselved. The OP doesn't pass e.g. `&a`, but `&a[0]`. That the pointers happen to be equivalent doesn't make it semantically correct. Even less so when `a` is used as an array of arrays which `a_vec` most definitely isn't. Either the OP have been *too* smart, or not smart enough. Either is bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having `c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];` inside your loop only works if the `c` matrix is initialized to zero.  However, the `c` array `float c[4];` in `main` is declared with no initializer, so it contains garbage, which when you add the results of your multiplication gives you more garbage.

The `valgrind` memory checking tool finds this bug.  Tools like this are invaluable for C debugging, and should become one of the first things you try when faced with a bug.  AddressSanitizer (-fsanitize=address) and UBSan (-fsanitize=undefined), both available in GCC and clang, are also very nice, but they happen not to find this bug.

This particular problem can be fixed by defining `float c[4] = {0.0};`.  (As soon as you initialize at least one element of an array, all the rest are automatically initialized to zero.)